# best practice for global variable in python

Tags: python, function, variables

I have the following code across different files. I want to understand what is the best practice to define the global variable so that I don't have to run the function again to get the variable value. File structure as below:

00.py

```
def f_token():
    global v_Token, v_session
    auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
    token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_username_password("https://xxx.xxx.dynamics.com/", username, password, client_id)
    v_Token= token_response['accessToken']
    return v_Token
```

01.py

```
from 00 import*
A_Token = f_token()
def f_meta():
    code here
```

02.py

```
from 00 import*
A_Token = f_token()
def f_anotherfunction():
    code here
```

03.py

```
from 00 import*
A_Token = f_token()
def f_function():
    code here
```

I only want to execute f_token once and reuse the value of v_Token across file 01,02, and 03. These 3 functions are not dependant on each other. They are being executed separately. What would be the best practice for this problem?

Comment: Maybe or maybe not best practise (that's out of scope for SO anyway), but a [Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/1270789) is one way to address this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this code could be multithreaded, you can control access to the global variable with a lock. The global resource starts out `None` and the first caller who finds that `None` acquires the token. Future callers notice it is no longer `None` and skip the extra work.

```
import threading

v_lock = threading.Lock()
v_Token = v_session = None

def f_token():
    global v_Token, v_session
    # short circuit when token already acquired 
    if not v_Token:
        # lock, verify no race condition, get token
        with v_lock.lock():
            if v_Token is None:    
                auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
                token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_username_password("https://xxx.xxx.dynamics.com/", username, password, client_id)
                v_Token = token_response['accessToken']
    return v_Token
```

You probably don't want those module level `A_Token = f_token()` calls in other modules. Simple import generally shouldn't do something as dramatic as network authentication. It makes things hard to test and code is generally less reusable. Just call `f_token()` every time you need the token.

Answer (score 0):

Save the value as a top-level (i.e. global) variable in a module.

```
module_A.py
-----------
A = something(...)
```

Then other modules can import that variable:

```
module_B.py
-----------
from module_A import A


module_C.py
-----------
from module_A import A
```

The `something()` function inside `module_A.py` is only executed the first time it is imported.